# Alternatives to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

In a Google App Engine JPA Entity a `java.lang.String` is limited to 500 character, while a [`com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text.html) has an *unlimited size* (with the caveat that entityManager.persist doesn't work with entities bigger than 1 Mb - *I believe, but can't find the reference about it*).

However, if I use the Google specific `Text` type, I would tightly couple my application with Google App Engine. I was wondering if there is a more lightweight way to achieve the same result, such as through some standard annotation.

Maybe, annotating a `String` with a JSR-303 annotation. If the size is above 500, it would know to use the non-indexed Text type. Example: `@Size(max = 3000)`

Obvsiously I'm just dreaming, but maybe there is some standard way to avoid App Engine specific data types. Anybody knows?

**UPDATE**: [found issue 10, Support @Lob JPA annotation](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=10) in datanucleus-appengine
*DataNucleus plugin for Google App Engine*.

Comment: Why not raise a feature request on the AppEngine plugin ? Trivial to implement actually. http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine

Comment: Regarding your proposed solution - there's no point in indexing any of your strings if you're not going to search on them. You're simply wasting resources by doing so.

Comment: And regarding your concern about portability: Realistically, if you want to take advantage of the benefits using App Engine gives you, you're going to have to write App Engine specific code. I would simply stop worrying about this, and just try and ensure you encapsulate things well so it's easy to change in future.

Comment: @NickJohnson I meant to say that Text is not indexable, and String (<500 chars) is indexable, not that I'm indexing every String. About encapsulating, ok without alternatives, but JPA 1.0 has @ Lob, that seems perfect for the purpose.

Comment: @DataNucleus, I see that [there is already an issue about it](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=10). @ Lob, seems a good choice. What does it mean "Status: Verified"? Does it mean that is already implemented and tested? Thanks

Comment: That is marked as Fixed, since all it is is support @Lob which means always save as Text or Blob. What you wanted (I thought) was to have it as a Text internally if > 500, otherwise as String (i.e different)

Comment: @DataNucleus yes, but was just a thought, before I saw that there is Lob, Lob is more than fine already and is standard.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you might have thought of this already; but I'm posting this anyway since it adds a point not covered in your question.  My solution here was to make it private, and then for my object definition I don't ever return a Text object.  I admit this doesn't accomplish your goal of avoiding the App Engine specific data type; but it at least makes it so that you don't have to rewrite code outside of the one class which relies on the Text object should you decide to port your application off of app engine.

So, for example, assuming text is a blogPost variable...

```
public class BlogPost {
  private Text post;

  // ...

  public String getPost() {
    return post.getValue();
  }

  public void setPost(String val) {
    this.post = new Text(val);
  }
}
```

If that code feels a little sloppy it might be slightly (I don't know how the Text#getValue method works internally) more efficient to do this...

```
public class BlogPost {
  private Text post;
  private String postValue;
  // ...

  public String getPost() {
    return postValue;
  }

  public void setPost(String val) {
    this.post = new Text(val);
    this.postValue = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Dave, thanks for the answer. I'm already doing this. Stretching this further, I could implement a BlogPost interface with specific implementations. It would duplicate quite a bit of code though.